# Self hosted windows service (Console App is running fine) on Windows Server 2016 RSTful api is not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, owin, windows-server-2016

My main question is:
What is the difference between self hosted service inside a console app and a windows service?

I wrote a Self-Host Web API Console application which provides a simple api. For that I used basically the MSDN exemple:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class HeartbeatController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var jsonToSend = GetJsonHeartbeatStatus();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonToSend))
            {
                var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = new StringContent(jsonToSend, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                return response;
            }
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        private string GetJsonHeartbeatStatus()
        {
            var hs = new HeartbeatStatus();
            hs.Toolname = "html Scraper";
            hs.Heartbeat = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            hs.Plant = "plant1";
            hs.Department = "departmentA";
            hs.Servername = Environment.MachineName;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hs);
        }
    }

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            logger.Info("In OnStart");

            var UserDomain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
            var Port = "8377";
            string baseAddress = string.Format("http://{0}.{1}:{2}", Environment.MachineName, UserDomain, Port);

            var completeAddress = baseAddress + "/api/heartbeat";
            try
            {
                host = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseAddress);
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var response = client.GetAsync(completeAddress).Result;

                logger.Info("Api address: {0}", completeAddress);
                logger.Info("Service Host started @{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Info("{0}", ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (host != null)
                {
                    host.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Next Step was to write a Firewall inbound role to get access to the port.

Then I tested it on our Windows Server 2016 Standard.

-> Test passed in Postman on another machine!

Now as you already saw (in the code) I took the code to a Windows Service Application (user= Local System). I am logging in Windows Event and I have no error in starting the host (that's why I used the try catch).

-> Test with the browser on the server failed and also with Postman on a different machine.

I figured out that I have to reserve the path with `netsh`

I tried:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8377/api/heartbeat  user=everyone`

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://machineName.corp:8377/api/heartbeat/ user=everyone`

Installed the Service application with my user (admin) and set up the urls

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8377/api/heartbeat  user=myUser`

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://machineName.corp:8377/api/heartbeat/ user=myUser`

-> Test with the browser on the server failed and also with Postman on a different machine.

At this point I could not find any solution why my api is not working.

Does anybody have any ideas?

-edit-

Console appöication:

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -na | find "8378"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8378           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8378              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [fe80::5505:852c:952e:74f%6]:8378  [fe80::5505:852c:952e:74f%6]:62555  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [fe80::5505:852c:952e:74f%6]:62555  [fe80::5505:852c:952e:74f%6]:8378  ESTABLISHED

Windows Service application:

C:\Windows\system32>netstat -na | find "8377"
no response!